# Tkinter colours lighter on OS X

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, colors, tkinter

Take this simple example:

```
import Tkinter

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.configure(bg="#000000")
root.configure(borderwidth=20)
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (200, 200, 200, 200))

frame = Tkinter.Frame(root, bg="#444444", borderwidth=20)
frame.pack(fill=Tkinter.BOTH)

frame2 = Tkinter.Frame(frame, bg="#999999", height=120)
frame2.pack(fill=Tkinter.BOTH)
root.mainloop()
```

If you run this on OS X and then open up DigitalColor Meter and hover over each box, you will see that the two lighter grey colours don't match what is in the code.
If I hover over the the inner square, I get `#A9A9A9` (instead of `#999999`), and the middle square gives `#565656` (instead of `#444444`).

I'm running OS X 10.9 with Python 2.7.8, Tc/Tk 8.5 (Tkinter specifies `__version__ = '$Revision: 81008 $'`)

Has anybody else experienced this problem, and if so what is the right fix?

Comment: Which RGB mode are you using to display the RGB values? If I use sRGB, it works as expect. Are you sure `aperture size` it's at the minimum value?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're referring to @Rinzler. This is not for images but for the frames created by Tkinter. I can't find anything on Tkinter sRGB or aperture size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI - for an answer to this question, so my post on the tkinter-python mailing list:
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2015-January/003690.html