# Why doesn't tkinter use the exact color specified?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm using tkinter's Canvas to draw some shapes and text in an app. I've noticed that the colors I specify are being changed slightly, they look washed out. For example, when I specify a fill color as '#ff0000' or even simply as 'red', the RGB values that appear on the screen are (255, 32, 26), when I expect them to be (255, 0, 0). Anyone know why, or how to specify the colors exactly?

Comment: How are you determine the values that are really being used?

Comment: @BryanOakley With Apple's Digital Color Meter, which is what I normally use. Even if the meter was giving me the wrong values for some reason, I can compare it side by side on the screen with my color proof, and I can see the difference plain as day.

Comment: This looks relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166029/tkinter-colours-lighter-on-os-x Also, http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.tkinter/3643

Comment: @PM2Ring It is the exact same problem, however not very useful as an answer. One thing those links prove is that stackoverflow's style of forum is superior to most other forums.

Comment: Well, I only said those links look relevant... However, this page, linked from my 2nd link does look helpful: https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/